# JWT Token Validation using Mule

Tags: validation, mule, jwt, token, using

I am trying to create an oAuth policy to protect an API using an JWT access token. That token can be validated by calling an external URL.

I am using the following RAML for my Mule proxy.

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Custom API
version: 1
baseUri: http://localhost:8081
securitySchemes:
  oauth_2_0:
    description: |
      This API supports OAuth 2.0 for authenticating all API requests.
    type: OAuth 2.0
    describedBy:
      headers:
        authorization:
          description: |
             Used to send a valid OAuth 2 access token. Do not use with the "access_token" query
             string parameter.
          type: string      
      responses:
        401:
          description: |
            Bad or expired token. This can happen if the user or the API revoked or expired an
            access token. To fix, you should re-authenticate the user.
        403:
          description: |
            Bad OAuth request (wrong consumer key, bad nonce, expired timestamp...). Unfortunately,
            re-authenticating the user won't help here.
/hello:
  get:
  securedBy: [oauth_2_0]
```

However, mule is not able to send the Authorization header while validating against the external service.

Comment: What do you mean by "mule is not able to send the Authorization header"? Are you explicitly setting Authorization header while calling the external service from mule?

Comment: When I verify all the headers inside Authorization service, the header named "Authorization" is missing

Comment: You need to set the Authorization header when you call external service. Please share your code so it's easier for us to understand where the issue is.

Comment: I don't have code for that. This is through OAuth policy in API manager.

Answer (score 0):

The RAML that you posted is fine, but informative only. You have to implement the JWT oAuth token enforcement capability either as a custom policy or as part of your Mule flow. Currently, there is no out-of-the-box policy for JWT token validation.

Usually, for validating a token, an external endpoint is called providing the token as part of the internal [policy] request. That means that the policy itself will parse the incoming user request, and extract the token either from the query params or from the Authorization header (removing the bearer part). AFAIK, Authorization header is never sent to the introspection token URL.

Comment: How to write JWT token validation as a custom policy?

Comment: For Mule 3.x, you may take a look at https://github.com/mulesoft/api-policies/tree/master/jwt-validation-policy and the how-to documentation (https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/v/1.x/creating-a-policy-walkthrough). For Mule 4, general guidelines can be found at https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/v/2.x/custom-policy-index-latest